# How to automatically hide the status bar after scrolling it down?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to automatically hide the status bar after 3 seconds of scrolling it down.

currently, I'm doing this.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen();
    );
  }
}
```

I want the timer to begin as soon as the user scrolls the the status bar.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by, the user swipes the status bar?

Comment: @Shubhamhackz I meant dragging his finger from the top of his mobile screen.

Comment: Ok, in full-screen apps or games, users can see the status bar by dragging theirs finger from top to bottom, then the status bar will disappear after a few seconds automatically.

Comment: yes, scroll is the correct word :)

Comment: what's the problem with the above code?

Comment: Do you mean you want status bar to be collapsed after 3 seconds in extended mode?

Comment: I've replicated your code on a Pixel 3XL, and the status bar hides itself after "scrolling" it down. I don't understand your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may face existing issue on **SystemChrome**.

When setting System UI Overlays to `bottom` or `top` only, the status bar/bottom will show persistently after clicking.

- [Flutter problem full-screen on android #23913](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23913)
- [SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays isn't sticky on android when only disable top #28426](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28426)

I provide a workaround solution that **detect** status bar appear and **react** to it by using `WidgetsBindingObserver`

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  var count = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  ...

  @override void didChangeMetrics() {
    count++;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if(count == 1) {
        SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
      }
      count --;
    });
  }
  ...

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I've bought a new laptop yesterday, I'll try to implement your solution when I finish setting it up, thank you.